# How do I form a URL in Django for what I'm doing

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

Desperate, please help. Will work for food :)

I want to be able to have pages at the following URLs, and I want to be able to look them up by their URL (ie, If somebody goes to a certain URL, I want to be able to check for a page there).

```
mysite.com/somepage/somesubpage/somesubsubpage/
mysite.com/somepage/somesubpage/anothersubpage/
mysite.com/somepage/somesubpage/somesubpage/
mysite.com/somepage/somepage/
```

Notice I want to be able to reuse each page's slug (ie, somepage/somepage). Of course each slug will be unique for it's level (ie, cannot have two pages with mysite.com/somepage/other/ and mysite.com/somepage/other/ because they would in essence be the same page). What is a good way to do this. I've tried to store the slug for a page ('somesubpage') in a field called 'slug', and make each slug unique for it's parent page so that the above circumstance can't happen. The problem with this is that if I try to look up a page by it's slug (ie, 'somepage'), and there happens to be a page at mysite.com/other/somepage/ and mysite.com/page/somepage/, how would my application know which one to get (they both have the same slug 'somepage').

Comment: I don't get why you have trouble finding the subpages.  Could you provide the model that is causing the problems?  This doesn't look that complicated, yet, you claim there's a problem looking up pages.  Please provide the model that's causing the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also store `level` and `parent` attributes, so that you can always get the right object.

The requirement to store hierarchical data comes up very frequently, and I always recommend [django-mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/). It's the Django implementation of an efficient algorithm for storing hierarchical data in a database. I've used it on several projects. Basically, as well as storing level and parent, it also stores a `left` and `right` for each object, so that it can describe the tree and all its sub-elements uniquely. There are some explanatory links on the project's home page.

Comment: Just looking through my old questions... thanks a bunch for all your answers back in the day man. You helped me more than you would ever know.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a CMS app. There's a [comparison](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CMSAppsComparison) of several Django-based CMS. If you want a full-featured CMS at the center of your project, [DjangoCMS 2](http://github.com/digi604/django-cms-2.0/tree/master) or [django-page-cms](http://code.google.com/p/django-page-cms/) might be the right fit. If you prefer a CMS that supports the basic CMS use cases but goes out of your way most of the time [feincms](http://github.com/matthiask/feincms/tree/master) could be something to look at.

edit: incidentally, most of the CMS on the comparision page use django-mptt that Daniel mentions.

Comment: I need similar CMS functionality in my URLs but I'm not building a CMS. Thanks for the list though